# Mononame is not generating Debug.xnb

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Today im having issues with the Monogame content pipeline, I tried building a .spritefont file, it did not throw any errors when building, but I get the following error when I run it:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: The content file was not found. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/home/unrhypercam/Monogame/Engine3/Engine3/Engine3/bin/Debug/Content/Debug.xnb"
```

As far as I know, this file is supposed to be generated automatically,
I also did not use the normal content pipeline, but the MGCB editor provided by Monogame
I cant seem to find anything on the subject, any info would help

**Edit**: I fixed the content pipeline, and it is not the problem, any help would be appricieated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in guessing that `.xnb` files should be generated automatically in your folder. I am assuming this exception is being thrown only at your code, and the Content Pipeline builds all your content without any errors. This can be due to that fact that the path to your content file inside your code is different than the path the content file is actually being exported to.

You should check inside the `\bin` folder inside the folder your `Content.mgcb` file is, and compare the path of your "Debug.xnb" file to the one you are using in the code. Since the content pipeline's export path can be easy to mess up, it's better to check in the `\bin` folder and correct the path inside your code

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for the reply, this fixed the problem, I had to mess with a few settings to it outputted to /Content and now I could run it normally, thanks a lot!